# On receiving a specific value I want to disable textboxes. Last 2 textboxes are not getting disabled

Tags: javascript

```
function setRCA() { 
 var env = document.getElementById("environment"); 
 var selectedOption = env.options\[env.selectedIndex\]; 
 var envvalue = selectedOption.getAttribute("env"); 
 var textBox = document.getElementById("rcarequired"); 
 if(envvalue=="3") { textBox.value = "Yes"; 
  document.getElementById("rcaheattask").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaTaskPriority").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaIncident").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaTaskStartDate").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaHour").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaMinute").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaPeriod").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaEndDate").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaDuration").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaeffort").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById("rcaTiming").disabled = false; 
  document.getElementById('rcarootcause').disabled = false; } 
 else { 
  textBox.value = "No"; 
  document.getElementById("rcaheattask").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById("rcaTaskPriority").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById("rcaIncident").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById("rcaTaskStartDate").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById("rcaHour").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById("rcaMinute").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById("rcaPeriod").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById("rcaEndDate").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById("rcaTiming").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById("rcaDuration").disabled = true;
  // These two do not get disabled 
  document.getElementById("rcaeffort").disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById('rcarootcause').disabled = true;
 } }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: First off, we need to see your HTML alongside the Javascript code. Secondly, make sure there are no typos in your code, as this could be the case (seeing as everything is camel case and these two aren't, maybe that's your problem).

Comment: <tr>
    <td width="250">
    RCA Root Cause:
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea id="rcaRootCause" name="rcaRootCause" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Root Cause...">${rcarootcause}</textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rows">
    <td width="250">
    RCA Effort:
    </td>
    <td width="150">
    <input name="rcaEffort" value="${rcaeffort}" id="rcaEffort" class="form-control input-sm" type="text">
    </td>
    </tr>

Comment: sorry I dont know how to add code. Stackoverflow is giving me error while adding code. hence I added it into comment

Comment: in your HTML you have the id as `rcaEffort` but in your JS code you are using `rcaeffort` thats a typo and the reason behind the issue.

Comment: Thanks Angelos Chalaris for help...

Comment: Thank you Manish, that solved my problem...